# How to prevent edit form from opening when not adding a new row in Devexpress

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress

I have this gridview in Devexpress.  I have a pop-up edit form that opens up
when I want to add a new row.  However, I would like to prevent the pop up form
to open when I try to edit a row.

I've tried handling the mouse down and double click events but I still get the
pop up all the time.

```
    Private Sub gvMFFSeries_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles gvMFFSeries.MouseDown
    Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
    Dim hitinfo = view.CalcHitInfo(e.Location)
    If Not hitinfo.RowHandle = DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.NewItemRowHandle Then
        DXMouseEventArgs.GetMouseArgs(e).Handled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub gvMFFSeries_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gvMFFSeries.DoubleClick
    Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
    Dim mouseEventArgs As DXMouseEventArgs = TryCast(e, MouseEventArgs)
    Dim hitinfo = view.CalcHitInfo(mouseEventArgs.Location)
    If Not hitinfo.RowHandle = DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.NewItemRowHandle Then
        DXMouseEventArgs.GetMouseArgs(e).Handled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Do you still need to add a new row?

Comment: yes, I need to be able to add a new row.

Comment: But using inline editing?

Comment: No, editing happens in the pop up edit form.

Comment: Ah, do you only want to add a new row, but not to edit an existing one?

Comment: yes, exactly.  Edit form will pop up only if I'm adding a new row.  No pop up when editing an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
Private Sub GridView1_ShowingEditor(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles GridView1.ShowingEditor
    Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
    If view.IsNewItemRow(view.FocusedRowHandle) Then
        view.OptionsBehavior.EditingMode = GridEditingMode.EditForm
    Else
        view.OptionsBehavior.EditingMode = GridEditingMode.Default
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

or this of Gosha_Fighten in VB.Net:

```
Private Sub GridView1_EditFormShowing(sender As Object, e As EditFormShowingEventArgs) Handles GridView1.EditFormShowing
    Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
    e.Allow = view.IsNewItemRow(e.RowHandle)
End Sub
```

Comment: Again @Abdellah you solve my problem!  Thanks again!

Comment: Good, I am glad to hear that!

Comment: oh actually, I just saw that now, I'm able to edit the grid directly (without the popup).  I would like to disable the editing possibility.

Comment: You must add : `e.Cancel = True` in `Else` bloc like answer.

Answer (score 2):

While the approach provided by Abdellah may work, it's not recommended to switch the grid edit mode when the grid is about to edit data. Instead, the grid provides a dedicated event for this purpose. I suggest you use the [GridView.EditFormShowing](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_EditFormShowingtopic) event to achieve this goal. The event provides the e.Allow and e.RowHandle to prevent an edit form from being shown and to identify the current row.

```
private void gridView1_EditFormShowing(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.EditFormShowingEventArgs e) {
    GridView view = (GridView)sender;
    e.Allow = view.IsNewItemRow(e.RowHandle);
}
```

Comment: Yes! @Gosha_Fighten you are right, good answer. i make a upvote; if you allow me, I shall answer and put it in vb.net.

Comment: sure @AbdellahOUMGHAR

Comment: Thanks @Gosha_Fighten !  Could you provide us with more details as to the why this is better?

Comment: @Eric The EditFormShowing event is special designed for your task. Changing the grid edit mode leads to changing editing strategy. Those strategies require specific event life-cycle. So, changing a strategy in the middle of that cycle may lead to incorrect grid operation.

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten Thanks for the clarification.